# How to replace text and add a other specific text at the end of that line in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file containing below text for example:

```
the brown fox
the red fox
the brown cat
```

I want to replace **"brown"** with **"yellow"** and add **"edited"** at the end of line so that content of the file would be:

```
the yellow fox edited
the red fox
the yellow cat edited
```

Please tell me the solution!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe with a regex? $ matches end of the line. try messing around with https://regexr.com/

Comment: I will try it, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\bbrown\b(.+)$`
- Replace with: `yellow$1 edited`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\bbrown\b       # literally brown surround with word boundaries to avoid matching "brownies" or "whateverbrown"
(.+)            # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
$               # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
yellow          # literally
$1              # content of group 1 (every thing after brown) followed by a space
edited          # literally
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: This helps me a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This will need to be done in two steps:

**Ctrl + H**

First step: using regex (make sure "Regular expression" is toggled in Search Mode below), find if sentence contains **brown** and append **edited** to end of sentence:

[image]

```
the brown fox edited
the red fox
the brown cat edited
```

Second step is easy - replace **brown** with **yellow**.

```
the yellow fox edited
the red fox
the yellow cat edited
```